# 400 bad request after config apache to server static reactjs build

Tags: reactjs, apache, deployment

I am trying to deploy a static reactjs production build on an apache server. I have followed all the instructions I can find online, which basically involved allowing apache to serve routes back to index.html so that react router can route the request. The problem is now I just get a 400 bad request error

I have already added the snippet which can be found in the react app docs:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

This takes care of the not found error I had at first, of course, but still, now I have the 400 bad request error.

What should happen is apache should route everything to index.html so that react router can then handling the routing. But apache is getting stuck on this bad request error. Also, if there is a better/easier way to deploy a static build I am willing to go that route, instead of using apache.

EDIT: SOLVED! I just needed a different apache config bit: https://gist.github.com/ywwwtseng/63c36ccb58a25a09f7096bbb602ac1de#gistcomment-2807171